# How to define UID in Firebase Auth on provider sign in

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-identity

I need to define the UID consistently weather the user was created via a custom token on the server, or via third-party provider.  If there is no way to define the UID initially, is there a process for either:

1. Creating a new user BEFORE the provider-login so that the provider credentials can be linked
2. After the user is created (with the UID from the provider) creating a new user with the desired UID, migrating the credentials over, and then deleting the original user.

They both seem like difficult ways to go about what should be a generally straight-forward problem.

EDIT:

We create a backend unique integer User ID and store it in a SQL db. That userID is used to identify the user in all cases. If a user is created via a standard sign-up process, they will be created, and then stored in Firesbase Auth with that userID. If a third-party provider creates the account, it is stored in Firebase Auth with a UID created by the the provider. This UID may be a string, which would mean that if we were to try to store that in the DB, our entire codebase would need to migrate the type UID from an int to a string.  Instead, it would be much easier if the value of the UID in firebase Auth was the same as the UID that we create, which is able to be done when we first create the user, but NOT when the third-party provider creates it. We don't to maintain multiple UserIDs i.e., our UserID will NOT be the same as the providerID, so to grab the user and validate tokens, we want to user our UserID, not the providers UID.

Comment: Your question reads like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of asking us to help you fix your solution, explain the actual problem you're trying to solve with this dual-identity-provider solution.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've updated the question with an edit to further clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written up this quick test function to migrate over to a desired UID.  This function isn't perfect and could use some more error handling, e.g., if you had a problem importing the new user, the user would have been deleted and lost, but in initial testing, this is what I'm looking for. It would be ideal if the admin SDK would include something like this, but a touch more robust.

Written in Go:

```
    func (AuthImpl) MigrateToUserID(uid string, userID int) (err error) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    var client auth.Client
    client, err = getAuthClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var userRecord *auth.UserRecord
    if userRecord, err = client.GetUser(ctx, uid); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    userToImport := &auth.UserToImport{}
    userToImport.
        UID(strconv.Itoa(userID)).
        PhoneNumber(userRecord.PhoneNumber).
        CustomClaims(userRecord.CustomClaims).
        Email(userRecord.Email).
        EmailVerified(userRecord.EmailVerified)

    if userRecord.ProviderUserInfo != nil {
        var providers []*auth.UserProvider
        for _, providerUserInfo := range userRecord.ProviderUserInfo {
            providers = append(providers, &auth.UserProvider{
                UID:         providerUserInfo.UID,
                ProviderID:  providerUserInfo.ProviderID,
                Email:       providerUserInfo.Email,
                DisplayName: providerUserInfo.DisplayName,
                PhotoURL:    providerUserInfo.PhotoURL,
            })
        }
        userToImport.ProviderData(providers)
    }

    if err = client.DeleteUser(ctx, uid); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if _, err = client.ImportUsers(ctx, []*auth.UserToImport{userToImport}); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's up to the identity provider to define the account's UID, and to ensure that UID is globally unique. Firebase does not provide a tool to generate UIDs, as most identity providers already have such a system.

Comment: I'm not looking for a way for Firebase to generate the UID. We have a system for defining our UID.   Let's say the userID was `1234` . If the user created the account via our backend, we insert it with the UID `1234` . If we then link a Facebook account, we can still get the user via the UID `1234` but if the account was created with Facebook, we then can't grab the user via our defined userID `1234` thus creating additional code to check how the user was created in order to find which UID we would use.